# Set color for border of legend of JFree Chart

Tags: colors, jfreechart, legend

Problem is formulated in title. Details:

I have code in class-theme for set specific non-default-color for the border of legend frame.

```
LegendTitle legend = jFreeChart.getLegend();
legend.setWidth(100);
```

After this I need to set color for border of legend, but nothing like

```
legend.setBorderColor(Color.green)
```

I couldn't found.

Help me, please.

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a new color when you replace the legend's border:

```
LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setFrame(new BlockBorder(Color.green));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Realy, you are the greatest expert in jasper report and jfreechart that I ever met in internet.
Your help is very valuable for me.

Comment: Please, check another my question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254385/setting-currency-format-for-labels-of-vertical-axis-in-jfreechart