# Setting currency format for labels of vertical axis in jFreeChart

Tags: format, label, jfreechart, time-series

The essential of question is declared at the title.

More details: I have the Time series chart, and vertical axis should has labels in currency format like this

```
$100, 000, 000
$50, 000
...
```

Now I have the same labels, but without dollar sign and range delimiter.

For horizontal axis I used this approach:

```
DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy"));
```

And it works.

When I try to do similar

ValueAxis valueAxis = (ValueAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();

I can't find any method to format labels.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart()` factory supplies a `NumberAxis` for the range, so you can use `setNumberFormatOverride()` for with a localized currency formatter, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14443791/230513).

Comment: You may have overlooked this tangential [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14443791/230513) to your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14442404/230513).